# Zappa/AWS - Emails won't send and just timeout

Tags: django, amazon-web-services

Currently, I have tried both plain-old Django SMTP and a few different api-based Django libraries for my transactional email provider (Postmark).

When I run my development server, everything works perfectly. Emails send via the Postmark API with no problem.

When I deploy to AWS with Zappa, visit my website, and do a task that is supposed to send an email (Ex. Resetting a user's password) the page continually loads until it says `Endpoint request timed out`.

I have tried setting the timeout of my AWS Lambda function to a longer duration in case Django decides to throw an error.

Here is the error that was thrown. Just keep in mind this error only happens in production. I created a custom management command in able to retrieve this error.

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.postmarkapp.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /email/batch (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f6cfbd5dd30>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out',)): ConnectionError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/handler.py", line 509, in lambda_handler
    return LambdaHandler.lambda_handler(event, context)
  File "/var/task/handler.py", line 240, in lambda_handler
    return handler.handler(event, context)
  File "/var/task/handler.py", line 376, in handler
    management.call_command(*event['manage'].split(' '))
  File "/var/task/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 131, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/var/task/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/var/task/users/management/commands/sendemail.py", line 13, in handle
    fail_silently=False,
  File "/var/task/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 62, in send_mail
    return mail.send()
  File "/var/task/django/core/mail/message.py", line 348, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/var/task/postmarker/django/backend.py", line 66, in send_messages
    responses = self.client.emails.send_batch(*prepared_messages, TrackOpens=self.get_option('TRACK_OPENS'))
  File "/var/task/postmarker/models/emails.py", line 332, in send_batch
    return self.EmailBatch(*emails).send(**extra)
  File "/var/task/postmarker/models/emails.py", line 247, in send
    responses = [self._manager._send_batch(*batch) for batch in chunks(emails, self.MAX_SIZE)]
  File "/var/task/postmarker/models/emails.py", line 247, in <listcomp>
    responses = [self._manager._send_batch(*batch) for batch in chunks(emails, self.MAX_SIZE)]
  File "/var/task/postmarker/models/emails.py", line 276, in _send_batch
    return self.call('POST', '/email/batch', data=emails)
  File "/var/task/postmarker/models/base.py", line 72, in call
    return self.client.call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/task/postmarker/core.py", line 106, in call
    **kwargs
  File "/var/task/postmarker/core.py", line 129, in _call
    method, url, json=data, params=kwargs, headers=default_headers, timeout=self.timeout
  File "/var/task/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/var/task/requests/sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/var/task/requests/adapters.py", line 508, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.postmarkapp.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /email/batch (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f6cfbd5dd30>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out',))
```

I have allowed all incoming and outgoing traffic to my AWS security group in an attempt to fix this. Still to no avail.

Any help would be greatly, greatly appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: I hate these issues - how have you deployed everything.  You talk about lambda.  Are you using django with AWS Lambda?  Or is django deployed on elastic beanstalk or ec2/ ecs (docker)?

Comment: Zappa deploys to Lambda. Yeah, it's one of those drive-me-crazy-all-day problems, haha.

Comment: Is your Lambda function in a VPC? AWS Console -> Lambda Dashboard -> YourFunction -> Network settings.

Comment: Yep. It is in a VPC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The explanation is simple: A Lambda instance running in a VPC [cannot access the internet](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html#vpc-configuring):

> When you add VPC configuration to a Lambda function, it can only access resources in that VPC. If a Lambda function needs to access both VPC resources and the public Internet, the VPC needs to have a Network Address Translation (NAT) instance inside the VPC.

The solution is also simple, if annoying: run a [NAT Instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html) or [NAT Gateway](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-nat-gateway.html) in the VPC. (An alternate solution is to take your Lambda out of the VPC, but that is a much bigger change.)

I am running Django / Zappa in Lambda with a NAT instance for connecting to Amazon Simple Email Service and it works fine.

Comment: Thank you!! Still took a while to figure out how to "run a NAT instance" since I'm an AWS newb, but nonetheless this was the solution.

Comment: @Kevin can you please elaborate more on how to run NAT Gateway?
After I have created the NAT gateway I am not able to update the route table associated with my subnets to point Internet-bound traffic to the NAT gateway because I do not know what the destination CIDR should be .

Comment: @HossamAl-Dokkani: I suggest writing a new question about it. I haven't worked on this in a while and don't have any insight beyond what's in the documentation.